# how to set the uibutton position programmatically

Tags: ipad, ios7

I'm new to IOS development. Here I have a button on view, and I have setting the position as dynamically. but it's not working.

Content_IPad.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnStart;
```

Content_IPad.m

```
@synthesize btnStart;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.btnStart.frame = CGRectMake(500,715,46,30);
    [self.view addSubview:self.btnStart];
}
```

But it's not setting the position as I given. Can any one tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Where is the alloc/init of `btnStart` and other settings?

Comment: Are you using Auto-Layout?

Comment: @Larme, I have drag and drop the UIButton on UIViewController. Is it required to allocate again?

Comment: @Magento007: No. But the code you post didn't reflected the fact that its an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: @Droppy, No. I'm not setting the Auto-Layout.

Comment: @Larme, see my code is updated. now also not working.

Comment: Are you sure the button is non-nil when using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:
If you have set your outlet into the view controller and have connected to the outlet property, you don't need to add the subview again. Delete that line from code.

Second:
You probably are using auto layout. Check the first tab on the File inspector of the storyboard/nib file. By default it is checked. Try to uncheck it and run the project again.

[image: Autolayout]

Third:
I highly recommend to use Autolayout. At least try to don't hardcode numbers, e.g. use self.view.frame.origin.x instead or whatever you need. That's the main reason to use storyboards, the outlets are automatically placed in the right place.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you. now it's working. I'm using second method.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.btnStart.frame = CGRectMake(500,715,46,30);
}
```

what is more, if you **add button in interface builder and** you **do not remove** button in code with `removeFromSuperview` you should **not call** `[self.view addSubview:self.btnStart];`

hope it helps